# How to create session inside Loopback app with an AngularJS client?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, session, loopbackjs

Here is my problem :

I'm creating a web app with loopback (great framework :) ) with an AngularJS client, everything works well but impossible to reload the page without being disconnected. This behaviour is normal, however I would like to persist the session with a "Remember me" checkbox and just avoid to be disconnect on page reload. The access token is stored in localStorage, I think I have to create a cookie on myself but the main point, how do I avoid disconnection ? And redirection to forbidden page. Then should I do this on server-side or client-side both ? I'm lost actually...

I did start from this application on github if you wish to have a better idea of the project:
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-getting-started-intermediate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't need to create a separate cookie to store the authToken if it's already in localStorage. The part you will need to modify is inside app.js, the `.run()` block, which checks for the existence of `$rootScope.currentUser` to determine if you're logged in, which will not be persisted across browser reloads.

The code creates `$rootScope.currentUser` in [Auth.js](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-getting-started-intermediate/blob/master/client/js/services/auth.js). The `.run()` block of app.js simply checks for the existence of `$rootScope.currentUser` to determine if you are logged in.

So you'll need to change how you detect logged out state from simply checking for `$rootScope.currentUser` to attempting an actual call to `User.getCurrent()` or something. If you are logged in, the call will include the auth token in the headers, if not, you'll get a 401 status code response and you can redirect to the login page in that case.

Comment: You were right and in looking to the github repo of this project, I found this pull request who is working in that case:

[Github Pull Request](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-getting-started-intermediate/pull/7)

Thanks your help :)

Comment: (Glad I could help; accept his as an answer?) Be careful with the technique used in that pull request, since it doesn't *really* check if your token is still valid, it just moves the currentUser to localStorage from $rootScope, so it survives a refresh. When you are using an expired token, it will send you to a logged-in page, but you won't be able to see any data that requires an auth token in the header.